# Build tool for iOS and Mac projects

Tags: macos, ios, build-process, build-automation

I don't like to depend on the IDE (Xcode) to build my projects, I want an IDE-Free build tool for iOS and Mac projects.
In Java we could use Ant, Maven, Gradle, Raven...

Comment: What's wrong with using xcodebuild ? Are you trying to avoid even having an Xcode *project* ?

Comment: @Paul R Nothing actually, maybe it is my Java legacy and I have to drop it

Comment: OK - I was just trying to understand the motivation - if you don't object to Xcode *projects* then use xcodebuild. But if you want to avoid projects (or at least manually created/maintained projects) then maybe look at CMake ? (You'll still need xcodebuild though)

Answer (score 4):

We open-sourced our XCode Maven plug-in some weeks ago. At SAP we use it to build all our iOS apps and libraries centrally with Maven and manage dependencies in a product standard compliant way.

Some overview documentation and binaries on Maven central are still missing, but the sources and technical documentation are already available on Github. If you have questions please write to our mailing list. We will try to help you.

[xcode-maven-plugin1](http://sap-production.github.com/xcode-maven-plugin)
[xcode-maven-plugin2](https://github.com/sap-production/xcode-maven-plugin)

Kind regards, Alex

Answer (score 2):

We use successfully ant for building iOS projects. Basically we need it for continues integration (we use Jenkins). Most developers prefer using XCode IDE, but some of them sometimes (I would say rarely) use ant for quickly building projects from console after quick small change.

Basically you need to call xcodebuild using ant  task. But if you need more complex examples google for jenkins (or hudson) + xcode (or iOS, iPhone).

Comment: There's now an XCode plugin for Jenkins which negates the need to wrap xcodebuild in an ant/shell step https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Xcode+Plugin